# Windows 2008 R2: Admin user logs out but then when trying to log back in, same admin user name appears with prompt for password

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-accounts

For one of our Windows 2008 R2 servers, a very peculiar issue has appeared.

Using an admin account, I'm able to successfully log out. Then when going back to the server to log in, I'm prompted to press CTRL-ALT-DEL as usual, but instead of being prompted to enter a username and password, my admin account name appears and I'm prompted for just the password.

In other words, it appears that my admin account was never actually logged out, but just "locked" (i.e when user presses WIN key + 'L' instead of logging out). However, when remotely checking to see who's logged into that server using "query user server:[server name]", it shows that no users are logged in...

Any ideas on what's causing the previous logged in user to show as still being logged in? The server is patched up currently and appears to operating fine otherwise.

Comment: The behaviour you describe is absolutely normal, Windows usually remembers the last username, it doesn't mean you're logged in.  I don't know why you haven't seen this before, perhaps you had it disabled via group policy?

Comment: The other 2008 R2 servers in the domain don't exhibit that behavior though. The other servers will prompt you to type in a username and password. But this one 2008 R2 server will always show the last username logged in and only prompt you for its password. You have to click "switch user" in order to make the login screen prompt you for username and password as normal.

I have seen what you described for our WIN10 workstations though.

As for the GPO, do you know which one that could cause this? I'll try look into it. Perhaps this server is not receiving that GPO for some strange reason...

Comment: Found it... In Local Security Policy > Security Options, the policy's called "Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name". It was not set to ENABLED on that server, like all the other servers. Set it to ENABLED and now the logon screen looks like we expect in line with the other servers. Thanks Harry.

Answer (score 0):

In Local Security Policy > Security Options, there is a policy called "Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name". The default setting is DISABLED which will display the last user name at the logon screen. Set it to ENABLED so that the last user name does not appear.